# PostgreSQL: Update top 2 rows Syntax Error?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to write an update function that updates the top 2 id, where it is order by the highest total owed from a different table, and another condition is that id is NULL, and it should match the taxpayerid in the individual table.

Here's an example of the data table:

---

Delinquents table:

```
IRSagentID | taxpayerid
-----------------------
     NULL  | 1 
     23hj23 | 2
     NULL  | 3
```

Individual Table

```
taxpayerid | totalTaxedOwed
---------------------------
         1 | 2
         5 | 44
         3 | 34
```

RESULT (supposed to be)

```
3 | 34    (ordered by cost in individual table)
1 | 2     (ordered by cost in individual table)
```

what's supposed to update in 3 & 1 in Delinquents.
So 3 & 1 NULL variable will become theAgt So 2 are updated.
Update 2

Here is my code attempt when the update

```
UPDATE Delinquents
SET d.IRSagentID = 'theAgt'
    FROM Delinquents d JOIN Individuals i 
    ON d.taxpayerID = i.taxpayerID
    WHERE d.IRSagentID IS NULL
    ORDER BY i.totalTaxOwed DESC
    LIMIT 2;
```

However, I got this error:

```
psql:query1.sql:39: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "ORDER"
LINE 6:  ORDER BY i.totalTaxOwed DESC
```

I tried to do this way too

```
UPDATE Delinquents
SET IRSagentID = 'theAgt'
WHERE IRSagentID IN (
    SELECT d.IRSagentID
    FROM Delinquents d JOIN Individuals i 
    ON d.taxpayerID = i.taxpayerID
    WHERE d.IRSagentID IS NULL
    ORDER BY i.totalTaxOwed DESC
    LIMIT 2);
```

But the result is Update 0.

---

I tried to do select first to see the result, but I got what I want to see in SELCET, but changing it to update is annoying. I couldn't do the ORDER BY.So any other option? Below is the method that I used to get the result I want, but now it's just adding the update.

```
SELECT d.taxpayerID, i.totalTaxOwed, d.IRSagentID
FROM Delinquents d JOIN Individuals i 
ON d.taxpayerID = i.taxpayerID
WHERE d.IRSagentID IS NULL
ORDER BY i.totalTaxOwed DESC
LIMIT 2;
```

Comment: This is actually surprisingly hard to do in Postgres.  Have a look [here](https://www.myintervals.com/blog/2007/07/23/postgresql-update-a-table-using-order-by/) to get you thinking about possible solutions.

Comment: Why do you update an integer column to a string? `IRSagentID = 'theAgt'` will fail as `'theAgt'` is not a number

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: this is actually quite easy to do

Comment: oops. IRSagentID in my real database has strings and numbers in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the SELECT you have as the source of the UPDATE statement:

```
UPDATE delinquents d
  set irsagentid = t.totaltaxedowed
FROM (
  SELECT d.taxpayerid, i.totaltaxedowed, d.irsagentid
  FROM delinquents d 
    JOIN individuals i ON d.taxpayerid = i.taxpayerid
  WHERE d.irsagentid IS NULL
  ORDER BY i.totaltaxedowed DESC
  LIMIT 2
) t 
where d.taxpayerid = t.taxpayerid;
```

Online example: http://rextester.com/IJEE18608

This assumes that `taxpayerid`  is the primary key in the table `delinquents` (and is unique in `individuals` as well).

Comment: Learn something new here every day +1.

Comment: the set is a random case of strings, not the totaltaxedowed. 
Just it's supposed to set irsagentid = 'randomstrings'
Other than that, it works. I actually did this way before i came back and look at the answered. I just caught my mistake that I called IRSagentID in instead of taxpayerID

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name:  Yeah the irsagentid is a set of string.. sorry I didn't clarify, but I did corrupt my database, and I realized you're not supposed to do SET irsagentid = 'randomstrings'. I'm going to google and look around how to set the strings to the irsagentid

Answer (score 0):

In your code that updates 0 rows:

```
UPDATE Delinquents
SET IRSagentID = 'theAgt'
WHERE IRSagentID IN (
    SELECT d.IRSagentID
    FROM Delinquents d JOIN Individuals i 
    ON d.taxpayerID = i.taxpayerID
    WHERE d.IRSagentID IS NULL
    ORDER BY i.totalTaxOwed DESC
    LIMIT 2);
```

I notice 3 crucial lines:

```
WHERE IRSagentID IN (
    SELECT d.IRSagentID
     WHERE d.IRSagentID IS NULL
```

i.e. your nested subquery only returns `NULL`s, and `NULL = NULL` is not true, which is why nothing matches.

You should match on the `taxpayerID` instead:

```
UPDATE Delinquents
SET IRSagentID = 'theAgt'
WHERE taxPayerID IN (
    SELECT d.taxpayerID
    FROM Delinquents d
    JOIN Individuals i ON d.taxpayerID = i.taxpayerID
    WHERE d.IRSagentID IS NULL
    ORDER BY i.totalTaxOwed DESC
    LIMIT 2);
```

Comment: ohhh silly me. Thanks for catching my silly mistake.